# Open Bravo Default URL, how to view the list of users

Tags: rest, openbravo

I just want to know the default restful url for the openbravo, for example Let us consider a when admin logged in I should get the list of users and I don't know which path should I pass.

Answer (score 0):

The url to view the list of users in is 
localhost:8080/openbravo/ws/dal/ADUser you need to provide username and password for the authentication. The username can also be provided by passing l=username&p=password in the url

localhost:8080/openbravo/ws/dal/ADUser?l=Openbravo&p=openbravo